# how can we know, by what user the sql is executed in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm executing the sqls with different jdbc-connection strings. Each sql will run on respective database-user. Sqls are executing fine. But, I need confirmation like, the sql is executed with the user mentioned in connection-string. Is there any option which will emit the user involved to execute the sql to jtl ?

Comment: Already I'm getting the below information from jtl..
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,success

Similarly, Can I get the info like - By what user sql is executed ?

Answer (score 0):

We can make it possible by . Parse the username using regex and read the variable through BeanShellPostprocessor and put same to the jtl.

```
<hashTree /><RegexExtractor enabled="true" guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Regular Expression Extractor">
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">true</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">UserName</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">UserName=(\w+), </stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default" />
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number" />
</RegexExtractor><hashTree />
```

In Beanshell postprocessor read it:

```
String db_user = vars.get("UserName");
vars.put("db_user", db_user);
```

Note: Also, need to mention the variable name used here at jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties file.

```
sample_variables=db_user
```

By above way, we can achieve this.